# Bash script: Attempting to upload datestamped file via SFTP

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, sftp

I'm attempting to write a bash script that I can set as a cronjob to automatically upload a backup file via SFTP to a remote server.

The backup files on the local server are datestamped (e.g. backup-file-YYYY-mm-dd.tar.gz) and I'd like the script to only upload a file from the directory that has the same datestamp as the current date.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong? I can't help but think I'm missing something basic but I can't think what it is!

**Current broken script below:**

```
 #!/bin/bash

FILE=$backups/$(date+%Y-%m-%d).tar.gz *<<<<< I'm guessing this is where it's slipping up*

sshpass -p "remoteserverpassword" sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <user>@<remoteserverip)

cd /directory1/directory2/

put $FILE

exit 0

EOF
```

Comment: if you add a space between `date` and `+`  , is it working then ?

Comment: Also, what does cron's error output say?  That will usually get emailed to the owner of the cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about where it is slipping up, date needs to be eval'd prior to passing to here script. Reformatted for clarity but you could plug into the original script too.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     

backup=/tmp
today=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

FILE=$backup/$today.tar.gz

sshpass -p "remoteserverpassword" sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no <user>@<remoteserverip) <<EOF                                                               

cd /directory1/directory2/                                                      

put $FILE                                                                       

exit 0                                                                          

EOF
```